# RxDart, mapping each item of a list to another object coming from a never ending stream

Tags: dart, stream, rxdart

I've been trying to find a nice way of doing this but I had no luck.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

```
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';


/// Input a list of integers [0,1,2,3,4]
/// map each of those integers to the corresponding index in the map
/// if the map updates, the output should update too.
///
/// The output should be a list of Strings:
/// ["Hi from 1", "Hi from 2"; "Hi from 3", "Hi from 4", "Hi from 5"]
BehaviorSubject<Map<int, String>> subject = BehaviorSubject(
    seedValue: {
      1: "Hi from 1",
      2: "Hi from 2",
      3: "Hi from 3",
      4: "Hi from 4",
      5: "Hi from 5",
    }
);

void main() {
  Observable.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
      .flatMap((index) => subject.stream.map((map) => map[index]))
      .toList().asObservable()
      .listen((data) {
    print("List of data incoming $data");
  });
}
```

When running this, nothing is printed. This is because the subject never completes and thus the `toList()` never finishes building the list.

Replacing the subject with for example an `Observable.just(index + 2)` does work because the Observable completes and the `toList()` is able to collect them.

But the intended behavior is that the example should emit the new list of strings each time the subject is changed.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: `toList()` won't execute when the stream is never ending. Perhaps all you need is `https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-async/Stream/map.html with `stream.map(...).listen(...)`

Comment: I'd say `combineLatest` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) instead

```
BehaviorSubject<Map<int, String>> subject = BehaviorSubject(seedValue: {
  1: "Hi from 1",
  2: "Hi from 2",
  3: "Hi from 3",
  4: "Hi from 4",
  5: "Hi from 5",
});

void main() {
  Observable.combineLatest2(
      Observable.just([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), subject.stream, combiner)
    ..listen(
      (data) {
        print("List of data incoming $data");
      },
    );
}

Iterable<String> combiner(List<int> indexes, Map<int, String> map) {
  return indexes.map((index) => map[index]);
}
```

Comment: This works great for this example! Unfortunately, in the app I'm working on I have a `Stream<User> getUser(String id)` instead of one single observable containing all the users and therefore combineLatest doesn't working (because there can only be a maximum of 9 streams).

Comment: I don't quite get your issue tbh

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: shortly after posting this I realized that it completely depends on how the data is exposed:

If you have a method which has a signature like `Observable<String> getStringForInt(int number)` and you have to call it for every item in the list, my solution is the one for you. **Note** if the above method always subscribes to the same stream, changing that stream will result in multiple emissions (because combineLatest updates every item).

However, if you have access to the whole data container (like a Map

**Original Answer**

Ok, it turns out, it wasn't quite possible to achieve that with the implementation of rxDart.

The `combineLatest` constructor only supported up to 9 streams.

But since then, combineLatest with n-streams has been implemented and the solution to this problem would look something like this:

```
Map<int, BehaviorSubject<String>> subject2 = {
  1: BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue: "Subject 1"),
  2: BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue: "Subject 2"),
  3: BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue: "Subject 3"),
  4: BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue: "Subject 4"),
  5: BehaviorSubject<String>(seedValue: "Subject 5"),
};

void main() async {

  Observable.fromIterable([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
      .toList().asObservable()
      .flatMap((numbers) =>
      Observable.combineLatest<String, List<String>>(numbers.map((index) => subject2[index]), (strings) => strings))
      .listen((data) {
    print("List of data incoming $data");
  });

  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  subject2[1].add("I'm 42 now");
}
```

This will print:

```
List of data incoming [Subject 1, Subject 2, Subject 3, Subject 4, Subject 5]
List of data incoming [I'm 42 now, Subject 2, Subject 3, Subject 4, Subject 5]
```